# Android long Internet connect when starting after phone been locked

Tags: android

The issue I am having with my application is ,if the phone was active e.g. browsing facebook or using other applications that use Internet , when i open my application it fetches data using volley, the data is fetched and app is up in about about a second.

But if my phone was locked for a while , and then i open my application first, most of the time , it take over 6 seconds to connect and fetch and load the data. 
I tried other apps with these starts but they are fine, and in the emulator the app is fine ... not sure where to optimize

Comment: " I tried other apps with these starts but they are fine" - How did you determine that they don't have the same issue? E.g. when you start chrome, how do you know how long the first one or two HTTP requests take?

Comment: @JimmyB , visually, if i open facebook or instagram , you can see loading the new posts . On My app the app is loaded just waiting for volley to connect and return result